# Как передать данные из CCalendarDlg в CCalendarApp?

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

Я пишу мое первое приложение MFC, его смысл состоит в том, чтобы составить грегорианский календарь и у пользователя была возможность узнавать день недели по заданной им дате. Саму программу я уже написал и проверил в консоли, но при создании приложения MFC я сталкиваюсь с проблемой. Для начала я хочу, чтобы в главном окне программы находился Combo Box, в котором у меня находились бы все названия месяцев:

```
BOOL CCalendarDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    // ...
    m_combo.InsertString(0, "January");
    m_combo.InsertString(1, "February");
    // ...
    m_combo.InsertString(11, "December");
    // ...
}
```

После этого значение выбранного пользователем месяца должно перехватываться функцией GetCurSel:

```
int month = m_combo.GetCurSel() + 1;
```

(+1 так как нумерация в данном случае с нуля)

Далее мне нужно использовать переменную month в своей программе и каким-то образом вернуть её в аналог функции main - BOOL CCalendarApp::InitInstance(). Но эта функция является методом класса CCalendarApp, в то время как переменная month - член класса CCalendarDlg. Прошу ответить на вопрос, какими методами решается это проблема и с помощью чего можно передать вводимые пользователем значения в методы класса CCalendarApp?

Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете вызывать [AfxGetApp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k9f064x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) чтобы получить ссылку на ваш CCalendarApp из класса диалога.

Вообще же эта проблема обычно решается за счёт правильного разделения приложения на части, классы, слои. В частности, наличие кода по работе с календарём в классе приложения - довольно странная идея. В вашем случае было бы резонно использовать паттерн MVP. Тогда вся логика по управлению диалогом легла бы на уровень представления, а логику календаря следовало бы вынести в отдельный класс, который бы использовался в представлении. А класс CCalendarApp был бы просто вспомогательным классом... просто для галочки.